# Ubuntu Upstart event when network is up and when the system is about to shutdown

Tags: networking, ubuntu, upstart

I need upstart event names for the following two events.

1. The networking is up and running
2. When the system is about to shut down

Answer (score 0):

Any script in /etc/network/if-up.d/ will be execute when the network is up.
Any script in /etc/network/if-down.d/ will be execute when the network is down.

Answer (score 0):

Event for networking up and running (i.e. any device but `lo`):

`start on net-device-up IFACE!=lo`

Event for going to shutdown/reboot (Runlevels 0 or 6):

`start on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[06]`

(More info in the [Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#shutdown-process).)